# What are some online sources for information on beer of high repute?

Tags: resources

When looking for source material to quote, often I find articles from a wide variety of places when it comes to beer. When looking for technology information, I find it best to simply go to the most highly reputable sources (such as a source authored by Mozilla, Google, Microsoft, etc.).

Are there any readily available online sources of high repute for beer?

Comment: Possibly too broad. There are many acceptable answers to this question.

Comment: Aside from being too broad, the answers would be primarily opinion based and the purpose of this site is to become an online source of high repute for beer. I suggest that when you come across an article, asking questions about it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quire a few poorly-sourced beer blogs out there, many of whom get their information from other beer blogs.  If you want high-quality information, I'd suggest:

- Well-known authors.  Anything by [Michael Jackson](http://www.beerhunter.com/toc.html) is usually pretty well-regarded.  [Randy Mosher](http://www.radicalbrewing.com/rbauthr.html) is also reasonably trustworthy.  Honestly, any published author is likely to be considerably more authoritative than random blogs.
- Beer-related Organizations like [the bjcp](http://www.bjcp.org/index.php) or [the aha](http://www.homebrewersassociation.org/) and their magazine "Zymurgy"
- Industry publications like [the brewers association](http://www.brewersassociation.org/)
- Brewing literature.  There's a very active homebrewing community out there, and you can find answers to some questions on beer production there.  [How to Brew](http://www.howtobrew.com/intro.html) is one of the better ones available for free online.